# Prove $\sqrt{\frac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab+bc+ca}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}\cdot\frac{b+c}{a}\cdot\frac{c+a}{b}}\ge \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The following inequality is very nice and unsolved in AOPS for a long time.
I've tried to prove it without success. It's

> For any positive $a,b,c$,  prove that
> $$\sqrt{\frac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab+bc+ca}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}\cdot\frac{b+c}{a}\cdot\frac{c+a}{b}}\ge \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+b}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+c}{b}}.$$
> See also [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1656763p10502285)

As a user pointed out in the link, the problem has a geometric equivalent form.
$$\sum_{cyc}\sin\frac A2 \le 1 + \sqrt{\frac {s^2 - 8Rr - 2r^2}{2R(4R + r)}}.$$
I'd like to prove it by algebra way.

Since equality holds at $a=b=c$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$ we can consider the stronger one$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}\cdot\frac{b+c}{a}\cdot\frac{c+a}{b}}\ge \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+b}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+c}{b}}.$$
Now let $$x=\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}};y=\sqrt{\frac{c+b}{a}};z=\sqrt{\frac{a+c}{b}}$$then $x,y,z>0$ and $xyz\ge 2\sqrt{2}.$

We'll prove $$\sqrt{2}+xyz\ge x+y+z.$$
I got stuck here.

It would be great if you help me prove or disprove my subsequent inequality. Now, I see it is wrong inequality.

Also, you can share any ideas and comments. Thank you very much.

Thank you @RiverLi. The current proof is nice enough but it is not easy. Is there a nice proof?

Comment: What does "AOPS" mean?

Comment: Art of Problem Solving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof.**

Firstly, we find an identity.

Notice that for $x,y,z>0$ $$\left(\sqrt{x(y+z)}+\sqrt{y(x+z)}+\sqrt{z(y+x)}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{z}}+\sqrt{\frac{y+z}{x}}+\sqrt{\frac{z+x}{y}}-\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{z}\cdot\frac{y+z}{x}\cdot\frac{z+x}{y}}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x(y+z)}\cdot\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{z}}+\sqrt{\frac{z+x}{y}}\right)-\sum_{cyc}(y+z)\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{z}\cdot\frac{z+x}{y}}+2(x+y+z),$$where \begin{align*}
    &\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x(y+z)}\cdot\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{z}}+\sqrt{\frac{z+x}{y}}\right)\\&=\sqrt{\frac{x}{z}}\cdot\sqrt{(x+y)(y+z)}+\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}\cdot\sqrt{(x+z)(y+z)}\\&+\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}\cdot\sqrt{(x+z)(y+z)}+\sqrt{\frac{y}{z}}\cdot\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\\&+\sqrt{\frac{z}{x}}\cdot\sqrt{(x+y)(y+z)}+\sqrt{\frac{z}{y}}\cdot\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\\&=\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y}{z}}+\sqrt{\frac{z}{y}}\right)\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\\&=\sum_{cyc}(y+z)\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{z}\cdot\frac{z+x}{y}}
\end{align*}
Thus,$$\color{black}{\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{z}}+\sqrt{\frac{y+z}{x}}+\sqrt{\frac{z+x}{y}}=\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{z}\cdot\frac{y+z}{x}\cdot\frac{z+x}{y}} +\frac{2(x+y+z)}{\sqrt{x(y+z)}+\sqrt{y(x+z)}+\sqrt{z(y+x)}}.}$$
By applying the above identity, the original inequality becomes$$\color{black}{\sqrt{\frac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab+bc+ca}}\ge\frac{2(a+b+c)}{\sqrt{a(b+c)}+\sqrt{b(c+a)}+\sqrt{c(a+b)}}.}$$
Squaring both side, we obtain
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab+ac}\right)^2\ge 2(a+b+c)^2(ab+bc+ca),$$$$\iff(a^2+b^2+c^2)\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab(b+c)(a+c)}\ge 2(ab+bc+ca)^2.$$
By AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\sqrt{(a+c)(b+c)}\ge c+\sqrt{ab}; \sqrt{ab}\ge \dfrac{2ab}{a+b}.$

It remains to prove
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot\sum_{cyc}\left(ab+\frac{2abc}{a+b}\right)\ge 2(ab+bc+ca)^2.$$
Since $$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{a+b}\ge \dfrac{9}{2(a+b+c)},$$it's enough to prove$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)\left(ab+bc+ca+\frac{9abc}{a+b+c}\right)\ge 2(ab+bc+ca)^2.$$$$\iff (a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot\frac{9abc}{a+b+c}\ge (ab+bc+ca)[2(ab+bc+ca)-a^2-b^2-c^2].$$
The last inequality is true by Schur of third degree$$\frac{9abc}{a+b+c}\ge 2(ab+bc+ca)-a^2-b^2-c^2,$$and $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca.$

Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds iff $a=b=c>0.$

Comment: The identity is very nice.

Answer (score 4):

I think the stronger one is not right.
For example, let $a=8$, $b=1$, $c=1$, then

$$
\sqrt 2 + \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}\cdot \frac{b+c}{a} \cdot \frac{c+a}{b}}=\sqrt2 + \frac{9}{2}<6<\frac{13}{2}={\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}}+ \sqrt{\frac{b+c}{a}}+ \sqrt{\frac{c+a}{b}}}
$$
PS: I don't have enough reputation to add a comment under your post, so I directly comment here.

Comment: Thank you. You are right.

Comment: so the conjecture is false ?

Comment: @mick Yes, my approach is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch of a proof.**

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$.

Let
$$x := \frac{a + b}{c}, \quad y := \frac{b + c}{a}, \quad z := \frac{c + a}{b}, \quad w := \frac{2(a^2 + b^2 +c^2)}{ab+bc+ca}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{w} + \sqrt{xyz} \ge \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} + \sqrt{z}$$
or (squaring both sides)
$$w + 2 + 2\sqrt{xyzw}
\ge 2\sqrt{xy} + 2\sqrt{yz} + 2\sqrt{zx} \tag{1}$$
where we use $xyz - x - y - z = 2$.

Using $\sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v} \le \sqrt{2(u+v)}$ for all $u, v \ge 0$,
it suffices to prove that
$$w + 2 + 2\sqrt{xyzw}
\ge 2\sqrt{2(xy + zx)} + 2\sqrt{yz}. \tag{2}$$

Using
$$2(xy + zx) - xyzw = \frac{2(a + b + c)(a + b)(ab - c^2)}{ab(ab + bc + ca)} \ge 0, $$
we have
\begin{align*}
 2\sqrt{2(xy + zx)} - 2\sqrt{xyzw}
 &= 2\cdot \frac{2(xy + zx) - xyzw}{\sqrt{2(xy + zx)} + \sqrt{xyzw}}\\[6pt]
 &\le \frac{2(xy + zx) - xyzw}{ \sqrt{xyzw}}\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{2(xy + zx) - xyzw}{2xyzw}\cdot 2\sqrt{xyzw}\\[6pt]
 &\le \frac{2(xy + zx) - xyzw}{2xyzw}\cdot (xy + zw). \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Using
$$w + 2 - 2\sqrt{yz} 
\ge w + 2 - y - z = \frac{(a + b + c)(a^2b - a^2c + ab^2 - b^2c)}{ab(ab + bc + ca)} \ge 0, $$
we have
$$w + 2 - 2\sqrt{yz} = \frac{(w + 2)^2 - 4yz}{w + 2 + 2\sqrt{yz}}
\ge \frac{(w + 2)^2 - 4yz}{w + 2 + w + 2}. \tag{4}$$

From (2), (3) and (4), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{(w + 2)^2 - 4yz}{w + 2 + w + 2}
\ge \frac{2(xy + zx) - xyzw}{2xyzw}\cdot (xy + zw)$$
or equivalently
\begin{align*}
 &2\,{a}^{7}{b}^{2}+2\,{a}^{6}{b}^{3}+4\,{a}^{6}{b}^{2}c+2\,{a}^{6}{c}^{
  3}+3\,{a}^{5}{b}^{4}-2\,{a}^{5}{b}^{3}c-3\,{a}^{5}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}\\
 &\qquad -4\,{a
 }^{5}b{c}^{3}+2\,{a}^{5}{c}^{4}+2\,{a}^{4}{b}^{5}+4\,{a}^{4}{b}^{4}c-4
 \,{a}^{4}{b}^{3}{c}^{2}\\
 &\qquad -{a}^{4}{b}^{2}{c}^{3}-3\,{a}^{4}b{c}^{4}+4\,{a
 }^{4}{c}^{5}-6\,{a}^{3}{b}^{5}c-6\,{a}^{3}{b}^{4}{c}^{2}-5\,{a}^{3}{b}
 ^{3}{c}^{3}\\
 &\qquad -2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}{c}^{4}-3\,{a}^{3}b{c}^{5}+4\,{a}^{3}{c}^
 {6}+{a}^{2}{b}^{7}+{a}^{2}{b}^{6}c-6\,{a}^{2}{b}^{5}{c}^{2}\\
 &\qquad -3\,{a}^{2}
 {b}^{2}{c}^{5}-3\,{a}^{2}b{c}^{6}+2\,{a}^{2}{c}^{7}+a{b}^{7}c+3\,a{b}^
 {6}{c}^{2}+3\,a{b}^{5}{c}^{3}\\
 &\qquad +7\,a{b}^{4}{c}^{4}+4\,a{b}^{3}{c}^{5}+2
 \,a{c}^{8}+{b}^{6}{c}^{3}-{b}^{3}{c}^{6}-2\,{b}^{2}{c}^{7}\\
 &\ge 0. \tag{5}
\end{align*}
(5) is true which can be killed by the Buffalo Way (BW).

Comment: Thank you. I upvote for you. The final step by BW is hard to prove in usual way.

Comment: @Sickness Yes, it is not nice. I think there is better way to prove (5). Also, hope to see nice proofs.

Comment: @RiverLi I found a smooth proof.

Comment: @TATAbox Congratulations.